# NoSQL Workbench commit to DynamoDB incomplete

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I use NoSQL Workbench to design (single-table) the PK SK and Non-Key Attributes by creating the test data in VS Code as JSON, then import into the workbench. I repeat this over the course of weeks as I build up the key-designs. Once I like how it behaves I create the table in DynamoDB and start coding queries. Twice in the last few years I run into a situation where after awhile the Workbench commit to DynamoDB fails to read the entire test data set. I'm sure the test data is valid JSON. The workbench pop a dialog that states how many items were not committed. If I delete the new table and re-commit sometimes the number of items not committed changes. The DynamoDB cloud-watch log is not helpful. Next time it happens, I'll revisit this post and add the log message.

This is what I do when that happens. I use the Workbench to create a new model, export the JSON, then I snip the "NonKeyAttributes" and "TableData" table data sections and add them to the new JSON model and then import and the commit to DynamoDB takes all the test data.

Since these are single-table designs, the PK and SK are highly overloaded, but I don't see why that would cause the meta data to get corrupted; i.e., hence the need for a new model.

If anyone can shed some light on what might be happening I'd be grateful or an easier way to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this happens as NoSQLWorkbench defines the table to have 1WCU which causes throttling when trying to migrate large amounts of data, resulting in some items being dropped.

The team are aware of this edge case and it should be updated in an upcoming release to resolve this issue.

Comment: Thanks for your response. One of the first things I did was check the size of my test data and at 10KB it didn't seem that would be the problem.

Comment: Have a check at your table CloudWatch metrics and see if there are any throttle events.

Comment: I'm not well versed in CloudWatch, but as far as I can tell this is the only thing I've found for that table > ProvisionedReadCapacityUnits > 1 for 3 datapoints within 15 minutes.

Comment: In the DynamoDB web console you should see the `monitor` tab and in there will be a graph for throttled write events. Check that graph for the time period where you committed the model.

Comment: Yes! Thanks Lee, for hanging in there with me. I have a little dot in write throttled requests and throttled events at the date/time I was having the problem. I'll no longer just glance at these tables. Thanks again.

Comment: Excellent. I'll again relay the issue with our team, but I do believe it will be fixed in the next iteration. Feel free to accept the answer.